# DCIM/.thumbnails/.thumbdata3-* files get deleted but does not free up space on Nexus 7 Android ver 6.0.1

Tags: nexus-7, storage, photos, thumbnails

I am trying to delete .thumbdata3-* files in my DCIM/.thumbnails folder on my Nexus 7 Android version 6.0.1 tablet as these files seem to be taking up close to 3 GB of data. I followed instructions from http://www.worldcadaccess.com/blog/2013/07/how-to-reclaim-1gb-from-your-androids-disk-space.html. I was able to delete the big files and in place if it copy zero byte ones with the same name. I see the new changed files in the folder occupying zero space but the deletion does not seem to empty the ~3GB file.  On other searches, there was talk about a LOST+DIR behaving similar to a Trash bin to save deleted content, but I was not able to locate it. Is there a particular trash bin or cache location I should also check in? I do not find any searches with this particular issue and that is weird.

Has anyone run into similar problems? Any help in solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I looked at [.thumbdata files maxing out internal SD memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63993/thumbdata-files-maxing-out-internal-sd-memory) to check if the scenario was similar but I feel that in my particular issue, the thumbnail does not get deleted totally from the system as there is no reduction in space at any point of time after deletion. On the other hand, the other question talks about the thumbnail files getting rebuilt, which seems to be a different behavior.

Comment: tried addressing your comment in the last paragraph above